# How to reduce CPU utilization while using cv2.VideoCapture()

Tags: python, python-3.x, video-capture, opencv

While using ret, video = cv2.VideoCapture() and video.read () function for getting frames from a cc camera, the usage is low while no errors in connection to the camera. But if it can't capture frames from the camera, the CPU utilization increases to the maximum until the function returns the error. It is taking 20- 30 seconds for the error return. In a theoretical sense till we didn't receive any return the CPU must be a nearly idle state. But what is happening here? Can anybody help me to sort out?

```
detect_object(live_view_url):
try:
    video = cv2.VideoCapture(live_view_url)
    ret, frame = video.read()
except:
    print("Camera Error!")
    exit()
```

Comment: can you show some of your code?

Comment: The live_view_url is the rtsp link of any IP camera. The issue exist only if a network delay or anything which frame capturing from the camera is causing a delay. When the delay occurs the usage goes to maximum

Comment: cv2.VideoCapture is only frontend for different capture interfaces. Do you know what backend is used? You can set it manually, for example ffmpeg:
 video = cv2.VideoCapture(live_view_url, cv::CAP_FFMPEG)

Comment: does this do the same thing on both python 2 and 3 ?

Comment: can you open a python in a terminal and run video = cv2.VideoCapture(live_view_url) if it hangs its a problem with the url or a problem with the format that the webcam/ip cam is outputting through that url